# How to create observable only once?

Tags: rx-java

I have a specific funtion which should emit items whenever someone is subscribed or not. Also, this function should be executed only once and if someone subscribes to it it should NOT being executed

```
 Observable<CharSequence> observable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

            try {

                sseEventSource.connect(); //this should be called once when created;

                final SseEventReader sseEventReader = sseEventSource.getEventReader();
                SseEventType type = sseEventReader.next();
                while (type != SseEventType.EOS) {
                    if (type != null && type.equals(SseEventType.DATA) && sseEventReader.getData() != null) {
                        CharSequence data = sseEventReader.getData();
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(data);
                        }
                    }
                    type = sseEventReader.next();
                }
                sseEventSource.close();
                Log.d("SseService", "closed");
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `share()` operator.

```
Observable<CharSequence> observable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        try {

            sseEventSource.connect(); //this should be called once when created;

            final SseEventReader sseEventReader = sseEventSource.getEventReader();
            SseEventType type = sseEventReader.next();
            while (type != SseEventType.EOS) {
                if (type != null && type.equals(SseEventType.DATA) && sseEventReader.getData() != null) {
                    CharSequence data = sseEventReader.getData();
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onNext(data);
                    }
                }
                type = sseEventReader.next();
            }
            sseEventSource.close();
            Log.d("SseService", "closed");
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }).share() ;
```

If you genuinely want a hot observable use `publish()` and `connect()` to initiate the observable even if no one is subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using [Subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html), for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.getChanges().subscribe(x -> {
        //Data
    }, e -> {
        //Errors
    });
    m.connect();
}

private PublishSubject<CharSequence> ps = PublishSubject.create();

public void connect() {
    sseEventSource.connect();
}

public Observable<CharSequence> getChanges() {
    try {
        final SseEventReader sseEventReader = sseEventSource.getEventReader();
        SseEventType type = sseEventReader.next();
        while (type != SseEventType.EOS) {
            if (type != null && type.equals(SseEventType.DATA) && sseEventReader.getData() != null) {
                CharSequence data = sseEventReader.getData();
                ps.onNext(data);
            }
            type = sseEventReader.next();
        }
        sseEventSource.close();
        ps.onComplete();
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
        ps.onError(e);
    }
    return ps;
}
```

That way you can subscribe/unsubscribe on changes from subject when you want and establish connection only once. If you want to recieved buffered changes, please consider to use `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that this connect() and other stuff should be executed inside IO thread.

Comment: Is there any way to just create some Hot observable that would emit items even if no one is subscribed? All this code should be executed  at once in one thread. You want me excute part of it inside rx chain and one peice somewhere else.